# Costum "Add to cart" redirect for different "Add To Cart" buttons

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add different redirects for two add to cart buttons in WooCommerce. I have an "add to cart" button and a "buy now" button. If an user click add to cart, it redirects them to cart page and if an user click on "buy now", it redirects them to the checkout page. Currently I have a code that globally sets redirects to cart page after clicking add to cart button.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'change_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect_url');
function change_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect_url($url){
    $url = wc_get_cart_url();
    return $url;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2jn6.jpg)

Comment: You'd need to find a way to differentiate between the two buttons, figure out which one was clicked to trigger putting the product into the card in the first place. Maybe adding a custom GET/POST parameter could help.

Comment: The button seems to already be there, although you didn't describe how you added it in your question. The duplicate question does contain this explanation in step 1 (and maybe you should adjust your buttons accordingly), but step 2 and step 3 apply to your question